# how to migrate django database after model change?

Tags: django, model, migration

I have model M1. it had a field F1 of type IntegerField.
I created a number of items and filled their F1 with numbers.

Then I created new model M2 and changed F1 to be ForeignKey to M2.
makemigrations worked fine.
But migrate doesn't work - since it can't find M2 items corresponding to old F1 int values.
Moreover I can't delete M1 items through shell - attempt to get Objects.all() result in same error.

How can I delete "problematic" items of M1 without flushing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I delete "problematic" items of M1 without flushing database?

I would advise to do this as part of the migration, using the [`RunPython` operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython). I.e. you should manually edit the migration that Django generated and insert a `RunPython` operation that deletes these "problematic" objects, before `F1` changes field type

Comment: Do let me know if you're having any problems implementing it! 